# Validation for fax number in javascript using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one requirement wherein I have to put a validation check on fax number using Regex.The accepted characters in fax number are + . and numbers from 0 to 9. For this I have written the following javascript function

```
function validateFax(checkField) {
    if (checkField.value.length > 0) {
        var faxRegEx = /[\+? *[1-9]+]?[0-9 ]+/;
        if (!checkField.value.match(faxRegEx)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

but it is not helping me to check all acceptable characters. Moreover it checks only 3 to 4 characters, but my fax number can consist of any number of characters. I am new to Regex. Can any one kindly tell me how can I modify this function to make it aligned to my requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That regex doesn't look right. `[]` inside of `[]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/^\+?[0-9]+$/
```

The above regex would allow a `+` sign at the beginning of the number. Then 0-9 can appear any number of times (more than equals to one). So this regex would allow: `+123456789` `123456789` etc.
If you want to limit the minimum number of digits, you can modify the regex in the following way:

```
/^\+?[0-9]{6,}$/
```

here `{6,}` represents that [0-9] must appear **at least** 6 times.

Comment: Hey that really helped but my acceptable character also include '.'(dot). How can I manage that? and also what does that $ at the very end signify?

Comment: To cater `.`, you can include `.` in `[0-9]`. So your final regex would look like `/^\+?[0-9.]{6,}$/`.
The `^` and `$` sign are the start and end anchors. If `$` sign was not there at the end of regex, your regex would have accepted `+1asdf` as input as well. Because, it is beginning with `+`, which is allowed, and then is followed by a digit. So placing `$` at the end makes sure that there the whole input follows the regex.

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick:

```
fax.match(/^\+?[0-9]{7,}$/);
```

I am assuming here that a fax number has at least 7 digits and the + in the beginning is optional.